# Symfony don't move uploadedFile in right folder during unitTest

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have a Controller that get image from Form and move this image into a specific folder :

YML config :

```
parameters:
    app.logos_directory: "assets/images/logos/"
```

Controller.php

```
$logosDirectory = $this->getParameter('app.logos_directory');
$postLogo->move($logosDirectory, $filename);
```

ControllerTest.php

```
/** @var FileFormField $logoInputType */
$logoInputType = $form['team[logoFile]'];
$logoInputType->upload(self::$kernel->getProjectDir().'/tests/Fixtures/default.png');

$this->client->submit($form);
```

Using the app, the image file is moved in "projectDir/public/assets/images/logo"

but when I run PHPUnit, the file is moved in "projectDir/assets/images/logo"

I try to edit yml configuration. I've check "%app.logos_directory%" === assets/images/logos/ in both case

I want symfony move my file in public/assets/images/logo while phpunit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, a relative path is used.

Using the app, it is built relative to the directory of the file `'projectDir/public/index.php'`

Using the PHPUnit, well, it had to be the directory of the file `'projectDir/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit'`, but PHPUnit does the trick with `chdir('projectDir')`, therefore, when the script is further executed, relative paths are built relative to the project dir.

Inside your test, you can also use the execution directory swap trick, like

```php
chdir(self::$kernel->getProjectDir() . '/public');
```

But I think it's much better to change the main code and use absolute paths. Or include it in the parameter value:

```yaml
parameters:
    app.logos_directory: "%kernel.project_dir%/public/assets/images/logos"
```